# What is the equvalent of npm install in maven

Tags: java, node.js, maven, npm

i am new to java and have mainly used node.js for most of my projects. I have used npm and used the npm install function to download packages. In maven, is there a similar function that easily installs packages?

Comment: You can simply build your project via `mvn clean package` or maybe if you have integration tests configured via `mvn clean verfiy` . The given suggestion to use `mvn install` is usually not needed and installs the artifacts only within your local cache which will help usually...

Answer (score 3):

```
mvn dependency:resolve
```

Is worth take a look to mvn life [cycles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Answer (score 3):

There's also [`mvn dependency:go-offline`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html) to download the dependencies and prepare to run the rest of the tasks without any connection to the internet.

I was looking for a way to install maven dependencies during a CI job, while explicitly NOT compiling the code or running the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Keep all the dependencies in your `pom.xml`(You can think of this as `package.json`). If you are using an IDE like eclipse it will automatically download the dependencies for you. If you want to download the dependencies from the command line run `mvn install`.
You can find the corresponding XML for dependencies here https://mvnrepository.com/

Answer (score -2):

Maven doesn't have an install command. Before any task you run maven checks if the project was changed and downloads any new dependency you specified from **Maven Central** repository.

EDIT: Maven calls the resolver for most tasks you run.

Comment: yes it does, https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/, however is not the same that in npm install